# Refactoring sessions_controller in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I am learning to refactor my code but I am having trouble refactoring a sessions_controller I have in my application.It is violating the "tell don't ask" principle.I am thinking of extracting some logic to its own class but not sure how that would work.Here is the code from the controller.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    admin = Admin.find_by(email: params[:sessions][:email]) 
    if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
      sign_in admin
      redirect_to anasayfa_path
      flash[:success] = 'Başarılı şekilde giriş yapıldı'
    else
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:error] = 'Giriş bilgilerinde bir hata var'
    end
  end
end
```

How would I refactor this?I thought of extracting

```
admin && admin.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
```

from this method but would that be the best way?Where would I put the class if I extracted this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could extract admin lookup, as it may be reused in other actions.

Also, you could standardize your flash keys : `notice` and `alert` are two standard keys that `#redirect_to` understands.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_admin

  def create
    if @admin.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
      sign_in @admin
      redirect_to anasayfa_path, notice: 'Başarılı şekilde giriş yapıldı'
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Giriş bilgilerinde bir hata var'
    end
  end

  private

  def find_admin
    @admin = Admin.where(email: params[:sessions][:email]).first or redirect_to( root_path, alert: 'not logged in' )
  end
end
```

You have to use `#where` instead of `#find_by` to avoid exception if admin is not found.

If you want to keep your current flash keys, you can add in an initializer :

```
ActionController::Flash.add_flash_types( :success, :error )
```

Path in `#redirect_to` from `#find_admin` and when authentication fail should probably points to log in url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    admin = Admin.find_by(email: params[:sessions][:email])
    login_status = false 
    if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
      sign_in admin
      login_status = true
    end
    login_status ? redirect_to(anasayfa_path, :flash => {:success => 'Başarılı şekilde giriş yapıldı'}) : redirect_to(root_path, :flash => {:error => 'Giriş bilgilerinde bir hata var'})  
  end
end
```